# Eigenvalues of generators of rotations

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, lie-groups, lie-algebras, rotations

Given the commutation relation of rotations
$$[X_i, X_j] = \sum_{k=1}^3 \epsilon_{ijk} X_k$$
where $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is the [Levi-Civita symbol in dimension 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Three_dimensions) and $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are square matrices.

How can we prove that for all triplet of irreducible solution $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$, the matrices have each **only one zero eigenvalue**?

By irreducible I mean that there is no non-trivial projector $P$ such that $P X_1 P^t, P X_2 P^t, P X_3 P^t$ are solution.
(For instance the zero matrices of any dimension are solutions but only the $1\times1$ matrices are irreducible.)

I am also curious to see how to prove other things like for instance that the solutions are dimension $2l+1$ for $l$ integer.

Progress:

1. I observe numerically that the eigenvalues are $-li,\dots,-i,0,i,\dots, li$.
2. I will go to the library tomorrow to check in *Representations of the Rotation and Lorentz Groups and Their Applications*

Does anyone has a book in which this is explain in a way a physicist can understand?

Comment: The fact that you find eigenvalues $-li,\dots,-i,0,i,\dots, li$ is typical of skew-symmetric matrices with odd dimension. I am surprized you call them "rotation". Is it "infinitesimal rotations" ?

Comment: Yes sorry you are totally right. $X_i$ are the generators of rotations, so yes they are infinitesimal rotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in the book *The Rotation and Lorentz Groups and their representations for physicists* at page 157.

Here is a resume of the proof:

Define $p=i X_3$, $\alpha = i(X_1 + iX_2)$ and $\beta = i(X_1 - iX_2)$.
One can show that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the raising and lowering operators of the eigenvectors of $p$.
Basically if $p v = \lambda v$ then $p \alpha v = (\lambda + 1) \alpha v$ and $p \beta v = (\lambda - 1) \beta v$.

Then one can easily show that the irreps must be dimension $2j+1$ with $j$ half-integer.